# Dianoga errors in the logs for temporary file paths

Tags: media-library, dianoga, mediaurls

Getting the below errors related to Dianoga in log files related to temporary file paths. `Dianoga version` used is `5.4.1`

```
ERROR Dianoga: Unable to optimize {Image path} due to a processing error! It will be unchanged.

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: "~\Dianoga Tools\PNGOptimizer\PNGOptimizerCL.exe -file "C:\windows\TEMP\tmp5A88.png"" took longer than 60000ms to run, which is a failure. Output: 

Optimizing tmp5A88.png 
Source: Dianoga
   at Dianoga.Optimizers.CommandLineToolOptimizer.ExecuteProcess(String arguments)
   at Dianoga.Optimizers.CommandLineToolOptimizer.ProcessOptimizer(OptimizerArgs args)
   at Dianoga.Optimizers.OptimizerProcessor.Process(OptimizerArgs args)
```

```
Has anyone noticed a similar issue and tried resolving it?
```

Comment: What size is the image?

Comment: @Swathi Did you check this article that has a similar kind of issue and at the end given a solution with github link? https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/issues/34

Comment: @MarkGibbons The size of the images are around 2MB or around 24 MB.

Comment: @SumitBhatia Yes but the version used in github link is 5.0.0-beta.1.

Comment: 2MB should be fine, but 24MB, might be too much for the server to handle if there are a lot of images on the page.